# Linear algebra homogenous system

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a $3\times3$ matrix depending on a real parameter $x$. Denote by $S(A(x))$ the space of all solutions of the homogenous system $A(x)Y=0$. 
How can one find this space in generally ?

Comment: In the equation A(x)=0, is 0 the zero matrix?  Or is 0 a zero vector, in which case you want A(x)Y=0.

Comment: İts A(x)Y=0  I wrote wrong

Comment: Just to clarify. Is $S(A(x)):=\{Y \mid A(x)Y=0,~ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \}$?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an x such that A(x)Y = 0 for some non-trivial Y, this is equivalent to $det (A(x))=0$, so that is an equation you can solve.